# My AVAudioPlayer stops when transitioning scenes Swift

Tags: ios, swift, transition, avaudioplayer

Okay so originally I was using SKAudioNode in Spritekit to try and continue my music through scenes however I got redirected to use AVFoundation by another person on this site. I'm not all that familiar with the AVFoundation framework. All I want to know is how to continue the music when I transition from scene1 to scene2? The music is all set up and works with the code shown below.

```
var Music = AVAudioPlayer()

let myFilePathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Verm - Explode", ofType: "mp3")

    if let myFilePathString = myFilePathString {
        let myFilePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myFilePathString)

        do {

        try Music = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: myFilePathURL)
        Music.play()

        }catch
        {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

So how can I continue my song when transitioning scenes? Thanks in advance. Sam. :p

Comment: Is `Music` an ivar of your app (as opposed to the view)?

Comment: I have declared 'Music' underneath my class GameScene: SKScene { . The code shown above is in the DidMoveToView section not including the var Music = AVAudioPlayer().

Answer (score 0):

You basically put your code into a helper class (Singleton or with static methods ) so that you can access/play it from anywhere in your project.

This way you have a centralised spot for music playback, which makes your life easier, and it will play regardless of the scene your are in/transitioning too.

e.g Singleton way (class has 1 instance for lifetime of app)

Create a new swift file and add a class similar to this.

```
class Music {

     let sharedInstance = Music()

     var music = AVAudioPlayer()

     private init() { } // to make it a proper singleton

     func prepare() {
         // code to prepare your AVAudioPlayers
     }

     // other methods to play, stop etc
  }
```

Now you can also set up all your audio players at app launch instead when you play them which should also help with performance.

In your gameViewController or AppDelegate you call the prepare method

```
 Music.sharedInstance.prepare()
```

to set up all your players.

Than you can play them in your SKScene at the correct spot like so

```
 Music.sharedInstance.music.play()
```

or use some methods you created in the Music helper class e.g

```
 Music.sharedInstance.playGame()
```

I have a helper on github for a more detailed example.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-MusicManager

Hope this helps